# Making application locale aware (getting locale from URL)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need help getting the request locale code.

My theory is to define the locale in the URL, as such:

`http://localhost/en/services/web

for locale en (English)

OR

`http://localhost/fr/services/web

for locale fr (French)

`and then extract the locale from the URL and have the routes still work`

**The value would replace `it` in the `$lang` variable**

Here is my current code inside the `Application Module Class`:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
  $lang = 'it'; // this needs to reflect current request locale instead
  $request = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Request');
  $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');
  $translator->addTranslationFile("phparray",Pluto::path('language',"$lang.php"));
  $viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager');
  $viewHelperManager->get('translate')->setTranslator($translator);
}
```

`My solution would be to have the variable $lang populated with the request locale` and the remaining url portion pertinent to routing

I imagine theres going to be some modifications to my routing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening!

Are you using ZF2 or 3? I invite you to have a look at https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale, it does precisely what you are trying to achieve (even a bit more than that), in a proper way. I promised a few month ago to work on making it compatible with ZF3 but couldn't find the time for the moment, so I'll look into that later on, but if that suits your need just use it in ZF2 :)

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing you want is (if you don't want to add new module to your app):

For ZF3: https://gist.github.com/Itach1Uchixa/6ec75b8f2af47a0b63e3f52fa0285a24

For ZF2: https://gist.github.com/Itach1Uchixa/4840b004be2f2dcded19ec516e8aa6f1

Example config for ZF2:

1 step. Add line below to your service_manager config

```
'HttpRouter' => 'Application\Factory\LocalizedTreeRouteFactory'
```

2 step. Register listener to your event manager

```
Application\Listener\RouteListener
```

3 step. Your translator config must have locales key that must be like

```
'translator' => array(
    // this will be default locale of route
    'locale'  => 'en_US',
    // key must be locale that you want
    'locales' => array(
        'en_US' => 'English',
        'fr'    => 'French', 
        'ru_RU' => 'Russian'
     ),
),
```

Step 3 is optional you can change route factory to use another config
The config above will make you route:

```
/your/route or en_US/your/route for English
/fr/your/route for French
/ru_RU/your/route for Russian
```